# how to solve syntax error on sql on my flask app?

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I am working on a flask app, but when I try to run this query:

```
UPDATE Servi 
SET Orden = CASE WHEN Orden IS NOT NULL THEN '%s' END,
    Dependencia = CASE WHEN Dependencia IS NOT NULL THEN '%s' END, 
    Atencion = CASE WHEN Atencion IS NOT NULL THEN '%s' END,  
    Recibio_del_cer = CASE WHEN Recibio_del_cer IS NOT NULL THEN '%s' END,   
    Entrego_al_cer = CASE WHEN Entrego_al_cer IS NOT NULL THEN '%s' END,   
    Folio = CASE WHEN Entrego_al_cer IS NOT NULL THEN '%s' END,    
    Entrada = CASE WHEN Entrego_al_cer IS NOT NULL THEN '%s' END,     
    Equipo = CASE WHEN Equipo IS NOT NULL THEN '%s' END,    
    Marca = CASE WHEN Marca IS NOT NULL THEN '%s' END,    
    Modelo = CASE WHEN Modelo IS NOT NULL THEN '%s' END,    
    Serie = CASE WHEN Serie IS NOT NULL THEN '%s' END,    
    Unidad = CASE WHEN Unidad IS NOT NULL THEN '%s' END,    
    Delegacion = CASE WHEN Delegacion IS NOT NULL THEN '%s' END,    
    Accesorio = CASE WHEN Accesorio IS NOT NULL THEN '%s' END,    
    Falla = CASE WHEN Falla IS NOT NULL THEN '%s' END,   
    Ticket = CASE WHEN Ticket IS NOT NULL THEN '%s' END,    
    Status = CASE WHEN Status IS NOT NULL THEN '%s' END,   
    Reparacion = CASE WHEN Reparacion IS NOT NULL THEN '%s' END,   
    Salida = CASE WHEN Salida IS NOT NULL THEN '%s' END,   
    Reparo = CASE WHEN Reparo IS NOT NULL THEN '%s' END,   
    Servicio = CASE WHEN Servicio IS NOT NULL THEN '%s' END,    
    Reporte = CASE WHEN Reporte IS NOT NULL THEN '%s' END,   
WHERE Orden=WHERE Orden='%s'
```

I get this error:

> pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE Orden=WHERE Orden='a365'' at line 1")

Thanks in advance

Comment: the error is due to this line `Reporte=case when Reporte is not null then '% s' end,` Removed `,` it's too much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two issues:

1. extra comma for the last column update and
2. two where keyword:

```
UPDATE Servi 
SET 
   Orden= case when Orden is not null then '%s' end,
   Dependencia=case when Dependencia is not null then '%s' end, 
   Atencion=case when Atencion is not null then '%s' end,  
   Recibio_del_cer=case when Recibio_del_cer is not null then '%s' end,   
   Entrego_al_cer=case when Entrego_al_cer is not null then '%s' end,   
   Folio=case when Entrego_al_cer is not null then '%s' end,    
   Entrada=case when Entrego_al_cer is not null then '%s' end,     
   Equipo=case when Equipo is not null then '%s' end,    
   Marca=case when Marca is not null then '%s' end,    
   Modelo=case when Modelo is not null then '%s' end,    
   Serie=case when Serie is not null then '%s' end,    
   Unidad=case when Unidad is not null then '%s' end,    
   Delegacion=case when Delegacion is not null then '%s' end,    
   Accesorio=case when Accesorio is not null then '%s' end,    
   Falla=case when Falla is not null then '%s' end,   
   Ticket=case when Ticket is not null then '%s' end,    
   Status=case when Status is not null then '%s' end,   
   Reparacion=case when Reparacion is not null then '%s' end,   
   Salida=case when Salida is not null then '%s' end,   
   Reparo=case when Reparo is not null then '%s' end,   
   Servicio=case when Servicio is not null then '%s' end,    
   Reporte=case when Reporte is not null then '%s' end   
WHERE Orden='%s'
```